# when is checked attribute of check box element added to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I need to color all the check boxes that are checked to green and unchecked one's to red.

```
<style>
 input[type=checkbox]+span{
   color:red;
 }
 input[type=checkbox][checked]+span{
    color:green;
 }
</style>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="bike"/>
    <span>I have a bike</span></label>
<label> 
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="car"/>
    <span>I have a car</span>
</label>
```

It looks good when page is loaded. But later, when user clicks on any check box,thier color is not being changed.After debugging, I came to know that `checked` attribute is not added to input tag when user click happens. Can somebody tell me the reason?

I tried to put `checked` attribute explicitly then it worked well.

```
<button>Click</button>

    <script>
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.bike').attr('checked',true);
    });
    </script>
```

But I dont want to use any script to achieve this. Is there any way to make it possible?
when actually the `checked` attribute is added to check box to make it checked? 
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnwKY/1/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `:checked` pseudo-selector ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnwKY/2/))

For completeness here's the current support for it: ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked))

```
Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)       Internet Explorer  Opera  Safari
1.0     1.0 (1.7 or earlier)  9.0                9.0    3.1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but the responsiveness seemed faster in my mind if I set the `for` attribute for the label and the corresponding id for the input (when clicking label instead of checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

This is nice function for this, by using some class:

```
checkbox.on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

For class `checked` you can add some style like colors...